# Want rows to hide/unhide automatically as cell changes without having to run the vba everytime

Tags: vba

I don't want to have to press "Alt F8" to hide 0 value rows and unhind rows >0
I want it to Do it Automatically as the data changes.

This is the VBA code that works to hide/unhide rows with a value of 0, but again, it does not work automatically but rather manually.

```
Sub HideRows()

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each c In Range("V13:V898")
        If c.Value = 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf c.Value >= 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into the `Worksheet.Change` event.